# How to add a Style to a ResourceDictionary in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a ResourceDictionary named MyButton.xaml, in which the Style for x:Type ButtonBase is defined.

I know how to use this ResourceDictionary in order to define a Style in XAML.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://Application:,,,/Theme;component/MyButton.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ButtonBase}}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

I'd like to do the same thing in the code-behind.
Now I can write

```
var source = new Uri("Theme;component/MyButton.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary {Source = source});
var buttonBaseStyle = TryFindResource(typeof (ButtonBase)) as Style;
```

However, I don't understand how to apply this `buttonBaseStyle` to all Buttons (i.e. use it as the default style for Buttons) in the Window.
Could anyone tell me how?

Comment: please go throw this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643440/override-default-styling-in-wpf-textbox-based-on-presentationframework-aero

Comment: Thanks but that's not an answer to my question. I'm asking how to define a default style in code-behind.

Comment: @user4134476 Style btnBaseStyle = TryFindResource(typeof(ButtonBase)) as Style;  Style s = new Style(typeof(Button), btnBaseStyle ); Then add it to ressources and you can eat your cake. Note that Controls take a default Style as their Style (if they don't have one defined) when they load, once it's done they don't look for a Style anymore, you have to set it explicitely

Comment: @nkoniishvt Thank you very much for your help. I made a new Style s, but is it OK to just add it to the resource dictionary as `Resources.Add("buttonStyle", s);`? If the key is duplicate, this can cause an Argument Exception.

Comment: @user4134476 If you give it a Key then it won't be a default Style that applies by default to all Controls of its TargetType. You could TryFindResource and remove it before adding it

Comment: @nkoniishvt I've just found the answer `Resources[typeof (Button)] = new Style(typeof (Button), s);`.  Thank you very much again for your swift and appropriate replies.

Comment: @user4134476 No problem. Added the code as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a default Style in code-behind like this:

```
Style btnBaseStyle = TryFindResource(typeof(ButtonBase)) as Style; 

Style s = new Style(typeof(Button), btnBaseStyle);

Resources[typeof (Button)] = s;
```